# Access violation exeption in c++

Tags: c++, memory

I'm trying to learn c++, I've read a lot about it and get it, but every time I program something that uses OOP concepts I have memory problems.

This is the exeption I'm getting with my code:

> First-chance exception at 0x002EFB60 in Mathmatician.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x002EFB60.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

So my question here is:
what is wrong with my specific code?
And more importantly, how can I avoid such exeptions? Are ther rules of thumb  in c++ to avoid these?

And another thing: How can I avoid returning a local variable from a function that gets deleted (I assume just return the value itself, not a pointer?)

(More info:This specific code will be used to calculate derivative, with diffrent formulas like devision, multiplication, and more inhereting from the Form virtual class)

```
// Mathmatician.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
  std::string NumberToString ( T Number )
  {
     std::ostringstream ss;
     ss << Number;
     return ss.str();

  }

class Form {
public:
    virtual Form& Derive() = 0;
    
    Form& operator+(Form& const other); 
    Form& operator*(Form& const other); 
    virtual string Print() = 0;
};

class Number : public Form {
public:
    int a;
    Number(int a) : a(a)
    {}

     Form& Derive() 
    {
        return (Form&) Number(0);
    }
    
    string Print() 
    {
        return NumberToString(a);
    }
};

class Addition : public Form {
private:
     Form& a;
     Form& b;
public:
    Addition(Form& const a, Form& const b) : a(a),b(b)
    {
    }
    Form& Derive()
    {
        return a.Derive() + b.Derive();
    }
    
    string Print() 
    {
        return "("+a.Print();// + "+" + b.Print()+")";
    };
};

class Multiply : public Form {
private:
     Form& a;
     Form& b;
public:
    Multiply(Form& a, Form& b) : a(a),b(b)
    {
    }
    Form& Derive()
    {
        return *new Addition(a.Derive(),b.Derive());
        //return a.Derive()*b + b.Derive()*a;
    }
    
    string Print() 
    {
        return "("+a.Print() + "*" + b.Print()+")";
    };

};

inline Form& Form::operator+(Form& const other) // copy assignment
{
    return Addition(*this,other);
    //LocationNode* A = new LocationNode('A',1,2);
}
inline Form& Form::operator*(Form& const other) // copy assignment
{
    return Multiply(*this,other);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Form* n = &(*new Addition((Form&)*new Number(5),(Form&)*new Number(5))).Derive();
    cout << (*n).Derive().Print() << "/n";

    return 0;


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: Stop using `new`  (ESPECIALLY `*new` ! ) and you should find memory problems magically disappear

Comment: `using namespace std;` <-- pls no (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `return a.ContainsX() || a.ContainsX();` What.

Comment: `return (Form&) Number(0);` should fail to compile.  I guess you are using MSVC with its crappy lvalue extension. The same mistake occurs in several places

Comment: `prog.cpp:25:27: error: 'const' qualifier may not be applied to a reference`

Comment: @ melpomene It sould be `return a.ContainsX() || b.ContainsX();`
but that has nothing to do with the problam, I'm not using that method yet.

Comment: `prog.cpp:38:16: error: C-style cast from rvalue to reference type 'Form &'`

Comment: `prog.cpp:98:12: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Form' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Addition'`

Comment: `prog.cpp:103:12: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'Form' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Multiply'`

Comment: Never saw such unreadable code for month! It is a "casting" show, full of new, obscure semantics and lots more. C++ is a different language! As a programmer you must be able to reduce your example code so that we have a chance to get to the details problem. Simply C&P all what you have here is not the way SO works!

Comment: @YanayGoor If you're not using it, why did you post it? Please see [mcve].

Comment: @M.M Then how can I upcast properly?

Comment: @YanayGoor the problem is that you are returning references to objects that are destroyed when the function returns. The whole design is hopeless

Comment: What is your code supposed to do? It seems very simple algorithm, yet you try to do it in a very difficult way, making a lot of mistakes along the way. It's like trying to pick your nose, but putting on boxing gloves first.

Comment: @Klaus I tried to do it how I would in c#, How should I have done that?

Comment: Even in C# you should make this so complex....

Comment: Regarding the `Number::Derive` function, if you want to return a polymorphic value that is local to the function (i.e. constructing the derived `Number` and returning it as the base `Form`) then you might use `unique_ptr`. So do something like `return std::make_unique<Number>(0)`. The function def should be altered accordingly to return `std::unique_ptr<Form>`. Alternatively, a shared_ptr. The differences between them can be found readily online. If you don't care about the difference, use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @YanayGoor Removing all `&` would be a good first step.

Comment: @M.M I assumed that, but I cant identify where myself, and how to fix it.

Comment: @YanayGoor: No you did not! In C# you also would not use wild memory allocations ( simply impossible ). And obscure semantics are fully independent of the used language. Also assembler can be well formed and object orientated. But for a question on SO you have not to post everything and ask "Why it doesn't work". Start a debugger! But before, start reading a book for c++, objects, pro & cons for heap and stack, new and shared_ptr and so on. There is almost everything broken in your code.

Comment: I suppose `shared_ptr<Form>` would be one way to go about this , if you really want to keep the polymorphic hierarchy. (Personally I would consider polymorphism to be unnecessarily complicated this situation)

Comment: @iPherian it looks like the `operator+` and `operator*` have to store the inputs without destroying the original, so unique_ptr might not work

Answer (score -1):

You may see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091243/c-array-is-not-empty-where-it-should-be). The problem of **new** is that it does not clear the memory of the allocated space. The solution for **new** is to add the following line as long as you initialized the elements.

```
memset(element,0,sizeof(element));
```

Therefore you can ensure there is no garbage in the memory.

This answer is somehow based on my C language experience. Recently I found that C++ has another function called `std::fill`

```
using namespace std;
/* some function */
        fill(elem,elem+sizeof(elem),0);
/* end of some funtion */
```

Comment: That advice is several flavours of misguided. Your constructors should properly initialize the class members. If you start `memset()`ing things, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: I am saying that you need to zero those initialized members

Comment: And I am saying that `new` constructs the objects, that objects construct their members, and that using `memset` to zero those members is ill-advised. While the OP's code is terrible, he has initializers for all his class members, so your suggestion is not only ill-advised but also not the answer to his question. As for "learn C first", [don't do that](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk), it is also bad advice.